# How to align Haddock comments for function parameters in emacs?

Tags: haskell, emacs, comments, haddock

It seems that the only way to document function parameters is to [use the `-- ^ docs here` style](https://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#function-arguments). Unfortunately, this gets very unwieldy when function parameters are of different lengths. For example:

```hs
myFunc :: (Int -> String -> Bool -> IO ())   -- ^ documentation string #1
       -> Int    -- ^ documentation string #2
       -> String    -- ^ documentation string #3                         
       -> Bool   -- ^ documentation string #4
       -> IO ()   -- ^ documentation string #5
```

Converting the above to the following, takes a lot of manual effort:

```hs
myFunc :: (Int -> String -> Bool -> IO ())   -- ^ documentation string #1
       -> Int                                -- ^ documentation string #2
       -> String                             -- ^ documentation string #3                         
       -> Bool                               -- ^ documentation string #4
       -> IO ()                              -- ^ documentation string #5
```

Is there any automated way of doing this in Emacs? Or is there any other, more manageable way, of writing this documentation?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't answer the question on how to automate alignment of comments, but when types become long, I usually rely on a different formatting style:

```
myFunc
    :: (Int -> String -> Bool -> IO ())
    -- ^ documentation string #1
    -> Int
    -- ^ documentation string #2
    -> String
    -- ^ documentation string #3                         
    -> Bool
    -- ^ documentation string #4
    -> IO ()
    -- ^ documentation string #5
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is using <kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regex` `--`.  With a little more work, you could add an alignment rule in your haskell hook to align EOL comments (see align.el for examples), and then just <kbd>align</kbd> should do the trick.

Comment: Maybe `M-x` `align-regex` `-- ^`?